# Apache Spark metrics that capture SQL traffic? (bytesRead/bytesWritten)

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, metrics, azure-log-analytics

I'm using [spark-monitoring](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/tree/l4jv2) to capture Spark's metrics and transmitting them to LogAnalytics. Some of the default metrics include `bytesRead` and `bytesWritten` and are part of the [Executor Task Metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#executor-task-metrics). However, they have a limitation that the only capture traffic when reading/writing in HDFS, if I do an operation in an SQL database, it doesn't report this data.

My question is: Are there any metrics that capture traffic from/to SQL sources/sinks? Or is there any custom approach to capture this with a Listener?